# Comparing missing numbers in an array. PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, time, compare

I got this script which looks up taken times in this table and then removes those times from these three arrays. The arrays are times 1-24.

The ultimate goal of this script is to compare all the missing times from these arrays and make one big array with only the available times.

The catch is it needs to check if a time is missing three times in a row. If it is, that time will not display in the final array.

For example:

```
<?php

include 'db-connect.php';
if (isset($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['day']) && isset($_GET['year'])) {

$month = $_GET['month'];
$day = $_GET['day'];
$year = $_GET['year'];

//string together date
$date = $month."/".$day."/".$year;

//define the queries
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT start_time, server FROM classes WHERE date = '$date' AND server = '1'");
$sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT start_time, server FROM classes WHERE date = '$date' AND server = '2'");
$sql3 = mysql_query("SELECT start_time, server FROM classes WHERE date = '$date' AND server = '3'");

//define time lists for each server
$timelist1 = range(1, 24);
$timelist2 = range(1, 24);
$timelist3 = range(1, 24);

//unset the arrays with the taken times for server 1
while($query1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {

    unset($timelist1[$query1['start_time'] - 1]);

}
//unset the arrays with the taken times for server 2
while($query2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {

    unset($timelist2[$query2['start_time'] - 1]);

}
//unset the arrays with the taken times for server 3
while($query3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {

    unset($timelist3[$query3['start_time'] - 1]);

}

//now see which times are missing three times in a row and make one final array of available times.

//code goes here...

}
?>
```

Comment: You do not need to run a separate query for each value of server. Nor do you need (or want) to put quotes around numbers in your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your current strategy you could just store the number of arrays each time is found in, like:

```
include 'db-connect.php';
if (isset($_GET['month']) && isset($_GET['day']) && isset($_GET['year'])) {

$month = $_GET['month'];
$day = $_GET['day'];
$year = $_GET['year'];

//string together date
$date = $month."/".$day."/".$year;

//define time list
$timelist = array_fill(1, 24, 0);

while($query1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {

    $timelist[$query1['start_time']]++;

}

while($query2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) {

    $timelist[$query2['start_time']]++;

}

while($query3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) {

    $timelist[$query3['start_time']]++;

}

$timelist = array_keys(array_filter($timelist, 'equals3'));

function equals3($x){
    return $x == 3;
}
```

Now $timelist is an array of times that were found in all three queries. If you want an array of times that were missing from at least one query use this instead of the last few lines:

```
$timelist = array_keys(array_filter($timelist, 'lessThan3'));

function lessThan3($x){
    return $x < 3;
}
```

**Edit** for variable amount of servers.

```
// Here you can list the servers you want to include in the query
// In an array form so it can be filled easily
$servers = array(1,2,4,5);
$num_servers = count($servers);

// Convert servers into queryable format
$servers = '(\''.implode('\',\'', $servers).'\')';
$query = 'SELECT `start_time`, COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `classes`
           WHERE `date` = \''.$date.'\' AND `server` IN '.$servers.' 
           GROUP BY `start_time`';
$result = mysql_query($query);

$timelist = array_fill(1, 24, 1);
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
    if($row[1] == $num_servers) // `start_time` is missing from at least one server
        unset($timelist[$row[0]]);
$timelist = array_keys($timelist);

// Now $timelist is an array of times that are available on at least one server from the query
```

Please note that since your date variable comes from `$_GET` you should be very careful of MySQL Injection attacks. Someone could delete your whole database, or worse, if you don't have the right protection in place. Please read this: http://www.learnphponline.com/security/sql-injection-prevention-mysql-php

Comment: So this script removed all the taken times from $timelist array?

Comment: @David I'm not sure what a "taken time" is. The script above creates an array which contains numbers between 1 and 24 which were found in all three queries `start_time`.

Comment: When you call mysql_query("SELECT start_time, server FROM classes WHERE date = '$date' AND server = '1'") it pulls the unavailable times on that date.

Comment: @David In that case $timelist is an array of times that are unavailable on all three servers. If you want the opposite (so the array contains the times that are available on at least one server, use the code from my edit I just made.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '&' or T_VARIABLE on function equals3(x){

Comment: @David Yup, I forgot the `$` on `x` to make it a variable. I added it on now

Comment: Warning: array_filter() [function.array-filter]: The second argument, 'equals3', should be a valid callback and Warning: array_keys() [function.array-keys]: The first argument should be an array. on $timelist = array_keys(array_filter($timelist, 'equals3'));

Comment: @David which one are you using? `equals3` or `lessThan3`? Make sure that the string in array_filter matches the name of the function.

Comment: equals3, and yes they do match.

Comment: @David Hmm... It works for me. What version of php are you using? Does it help if you put the function before `$timelist = array_keys(array_filter($timelist, 'equals3'));` instead of after like I had?

Comment: This script works fine as you described it but I have explained what I need wrong.

Comment: It needs to only show the times that are not pulled up three times in the arrays

Comment: @David that's what the lessThan3 code does. Just replace the equals3 function with the lessThan3 function and change `'equals3'` to `'lessThan3'`

Comment: ok. Now what would you do if there was a range of servers, meaning there might be 10 servers. How would you do this without wasting your time writing out ten while loops and queries?

Comment: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource on $row = mysql_fetch_row($result)

Comment: @David Bah, I keep making stupid mistakes while trying to be fast haha. I should be more careful. I wrote `$server` in the query instead of `$servers`. Just add that `s` and it should work.

Comment: ok works now but $timelist became an array of the taken times.

Comment: if($row[1] < $num_servers) // `start_time` is missing from at least one server
        $timelist[] = $row[0];
missing { and }?

Comment: @David I don't understand? `print_r($timelist)` at the end of that code. If you put `array(1,2,3)` as your input array for $servers it should have the same output as the code I gave you before.

Comment: it's only displaying the times already in the table. and yes the array is set correctly

Comment: @David Ah, I forgot to include times that are missing from all servers. I edited it again.

Comment: @PaulPRO let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2502/discussion-between-david-meyer-and-paulpro)